# mock the server response even the server is unreachable

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient-interceptors

Things I know (*please correct me if I'm wrong, thank you :)*):

- `HttpInterceptor` works in a way similar to [Aspect-oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming);
- adding/modifying `httpOptions` can be achieved for requests;
- modifying the response with `clone()` can also be achieved for response;

#### My problems

*I want to test some libraries while their related servers can be down sometimes when developing I just care about the data no interaction with server is okay*

> Is it possible that I can just return a mock data already prepared without requesting the server when the request met some patterns **even the service lies in other libraries**?

#### My Requirements

- all the logic in the libraries stays the same;
- using the mock data to respond to the http request from the libraries;

#### Updated 2019-01-15

Thanks to the help of **@Sachin Gupta**, I tested the [`interceptor`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) further with this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpclient-interceptor-demo?file=src%2Fapp%2Finterceptors%2Findex.ts).

What have been done:

- `auth-interceptor.ts` to add headers for the request;
- `logging-interceptor.ts` added to track the request details and time cost;
- `data-mocking-interceptor.ts` to **stop** the request to the server and return the mock data directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-json-http-response-catch

If the server is reachable, the data is populated, otherwise mocked is sent as response

### Interceptor

```js
export class NoopInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler):
    Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
      let response = new HttpResponse();
      response = response.clone({body: [{"sads":"ewre"}]});
   
    return next.handle(req).pipe(catchError((err) => {return of(response).pipe(delay(10))}) );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is great when server response is `bad` but is there any other way that I can `intercept` before requesting the server? so I can do my filtering there? just wondering... thanks for help :)

Comment: The intercept works in that way only.. It intercepts before sending the request to server. If for some reason you need to mock the server even without attempting the request, you can replace the last line with `return of(response).pipe(delay(10))`. where the response is the object that we just created.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 other options to consider:

1. Use `ngrx store` where you could populate the store with either mocked data directly or return mocked data from your service (service being the one that sends http requests to server and returns data back to the angular app)

OR

2. Use service workers where you could return whatever you want based on your custom criteria. Essentially, what you're doing here is offline first PWA. This is even nicer approach as http requests (as a source of data) is completely abstracted away from its usage. All your app sees is service worker, and where service worked gets its data (http or mock) - your app doesn't care.

PS.
Service worker approach is somewhat similar to interceptor one but on a lower level as its not angular specific but a part of web tech in general.